# How is the route scope parameter used?

Tags: routing, route, link-local

I am confused about the route scope parameter in the output if /sbin/ip route.

```
default via 10.32.10.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
10.32.10.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.32.10.154  metric 9 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000
```

I [understand](https://serverfault.com/questions/63014/ip-address-scope-parameter) what an IP address's scope is and the reasoning behind it; however, why do you need scope for a route as well?  This seems redundant as any route with no gateway for a subnet is link-local.  Am I missing something here?